# Java NullPointerException on Minecraft MCP loadup

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, minecraft

I have made my own Minecraft Client (which runs fine in Eclipse) however once I had exported it as a .jar file, and put it in Minecraft versions folder with a .json file, it returned an error when loaded.

UPDATE------------------------------------------

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

I did the instructions to successfully export it, however it returned this!

Comment: Looks like you're reading something from disk via apache commons. Is this resource available outside of eclipse?

Comment: It seems there is dependency on file (may be config/properties file), which is not available at runtime.

Comment: If you really don't know what file it's trying to read, you can try [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on Windows or strace on Linux to monitor file access and look for the file-not-found error.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will have a look

Comment: @Rup How do I find a file not found error?

Comment: In procmon? You should be able to add it as a filter - I think it's 'result is NAME NOT FOUND', or e.g. add a filter 'result is not SUCCESS' to catch other errors. You probably also need to filter process name for whatever minecraft uses if you're flooded with output from system processes.

Comment: @Rup Thanks so much. Taking 9 Minutes!

Comment: It could not find launcher.pack.lzma.new in the .minecraft folder. Does that help?

Comment: @Rup It also says NAME NOT FOUND DENIED ACCESS: READ ATTRIBUTES  C:\Users\chipp_000\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\MYCLIENT\MYCLIENT-natives-1198506463397633

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Minecraft well enough to say which of those. Since the error is coming from the StringTranslate class it might be some text file or translation properties file you're missing? I don't know sorry. If you have the source of net.minecraft.util.StringTranslate then have a look at that, else see if you have an translation-type file in your Eclipse project run classpath that Minecraft doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it runs fine in your IDE.
Have you noticed that it has `1.8.jar` under Libraries tab? That means the "Client" in your Eclipse project is using some files(assets.*) inside `1.8.jar`. The Client project in your Eclipse isn't the original Minecraft source code. It is modified a bit by MCP scripts to allow you to launch Minecraft client properly in your Eclipse. You have to copy a lot of stuffs from 1.8.jar and I am sure that Minecraft Launcher can't launch it unless you modify your exported Jar file and *.json.

If you really want to have your own Minecraft.jar, below are the correct steps.
After you've done your modifications to Minecraft, save all files then close your Eclipse. In the directory(folder) which contains eclipse directory, you should fine `reobfuscate.bat` or `reobfuscate.sh`. Use the `.bat` version if you are Windows user, and use `.sh` if you are MacOS or Linux user.
After you run the file, you should see some files in `reobf` directory. The files in the directory are obfuscated files and can be copied to Minecraft.jar directly. Now, use WinRar or other tools to open Minecraft.jar(1.8.jar). Copy all the files in reobf directory to Minecraft.jar(and replace if the file exists). After you finished these steps, you've got your own Minecraft.jar!

Now you should create your own version profile in Minecraft Launcher.(Reference: [here](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/how-to-install-mods-in-minecraft-172/))

In your .minecraft/versions directory, you should put your own Minecraft.jar. Predict you named it `MyCustomMinecraft.jar`, you have to create a new directory called MyCustomMinecraft in .minecraft/versions. Now, copy `MyCustomMinecraft.jar` and paste it in `MyCustomMinecraft` directory. Then, copy `1.8.json` in versions/1.8 directory and paste it in `MyCustomMinecraft`. Rename `1.8.json` to `MyCustomMinecraft.json`. Open `MyCustomMinecraft.json` with any text editor, in line 2, you should see `"id": "1.8",`. change it to `MyCustomMinecraft`. Your line 2 should look like `"id": "MyCustomMinecraft",` now.

Open Minecraft Launcher. Edit Profile button > Use version: > you should see `release MyCustomMinecraft` in the list!

Comment: Oh, pretty sure you're new to modding. You need to delete META-INF directory(inside the JAR file) too. Don't forget to upvote ;)

Comment: Then it is your code error. What is line 41 in `net.minecraft.client.Minecraft`?

Comment: It is just a line break in the import area

Comment: I removed all line breaks but it still has the same error. I assume you are talking about net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.java

Comment: ._. `net.minecraft.client.Minecraft` = `net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.java` = `net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.class`. Edit your question. Post the whole code.

Comment: Yes. Also, I think you should post a new question.

Comment: here is the Minecraft.java. I have no idea what to put in a new question XD http://pastebin.com/eUU0SLKi

Comment: You should post it in Minecraft Forums in the modding section. The code you posted isn't the "original" source code but obfuscated code.